# How to hide UWP app from applist entry at runtime

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, runtime

Currently I can hide my app from system app list entry with this

```
<uap:VisualElements
    AppListEntry="none"
    ...
</uap:VisualElements>
```

But is there anyway to change this value at runtime? Or after application has been install.

Comment: Is there a specific scenario you have in mind?

Comment: I think you can throw some unhandle except to app too hide it.

Comment: I just thought if it possible like android that you can hide app from launcher? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this by design.